# Samsung Xpress C460fw can’t scan

Tags: linux, scanner

Previously had HP Pavilion laptop all was good but motherboard died.  Bought new computer installed Linux and Win 10, duel boot.  Printer works well under Windows 10.  However, in Linux printer prints but scanner is detected and turns on but won’t start to scan.

Answer (score 0):

Found two Linux drivers for the Xpress C460fw :

- Web-page [Xpress C460FW Multifunction Colour Laser Printer](https://samsung-printerdrivers.com/samsung-xpress-c460fw-drivers-windows-mac-os-linux/),
  with
  [Printing and Scan Driver V1.00.36_00.91 for Linux](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/DR/201510/20151027104839117/uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz)
  dating from 2015.
- Web-page [Samsung C460FW Driver](http://www.samsungdrivers.net/samsung-c460fw-driver/)
  with 
  [Samsung C460FW Linux Printer Driver](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/DR/201411/20141126155604469/ULD_v1.00.29.tar.gz)
  from 2014.

Before installing, ensure you can re-install your current Linux driver,
just in case the new driver doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error finally got the scanner to work:-
Download driver from:
https://support.hp.com/gb-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-c460-color-laser-multifunction-printer-series/17157233/model/17157235

Then followed instructions at:
https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/samsung-printers.html
Modifying the file name to that of the downloaded driver.

Thanks to all the comments received which put me on the right track.